# Binding RadListView client Side

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

Ok, the issue is like, I want to bind list view on client side. I have found solutions on forum and demos but i am getting error on set_dataSource(data); like set_dataSource is undefined, morover, i cannot also find  tag within client setting as it is shown in demos. I am using 2011.2.915.40 version of telerik.

Below is my aspx Code:

```
<telerik:RadListView ID="lstViewNotes" runat="server" OnItemCommand="lstViewNotes_ItemCommand">
<EmptyDataTemplate>
<table id="Table1" style="">
<tr>
<td>
<%=GetGlobalResourceObject("General","EmptyData") %>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</EmptyDataTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
                 <table>
<tr>
<td colspan="3">
<div style="width: 100%">
<asp:HiddenField ID="hfNoteId" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("NotesId") %>' />
<asp:LinkButton ID="lblCreate" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("UserName") %>' CssClass="label_n_t"
CommandName="Select" /><asp:LinkButton ID="NameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CreateDate") %>'
CssClass="label_n_t" CommandName="Select" /></div>
<div style="width: 100%">
<asp:LinkButton ID="lblNotesDesc" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("MemoDesc") %>' CssClass="label_n_c"
CommandName="Select" /><br />
<br />
</div>
</td>
</tr>
                  </table>
</ItemTemplate>
</telerik:RadListView>
```

Below is my JS Code:

```
var listView = $find('<%= lstMemo.ClientID%>');
listView.set_dataSource(result.lstMemo);
listView.dataBind();
```

I have updated this issue on telerik forums too, but i am not getting any response. Respond me back if any one of you have a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't be available until the client-side AJAX framework has fully loaded.

> To bind RadListView to a javascript array, use the set_dataSource() and dataBind() APIs in a point after the client-side AJAX framework (and RadListView) has loaded

What does your datasource `result` look like?  Is it an array? ASMX web service? WCF service?

> **Binding to Javascript Arrays** 
>   To bind RadListView to a javascript
>   array, use the set_dataSource() and dataBind() APIs in a point after
>   the client-side AJAX framework (and RadListView) has loaded:

```
protected override void
OnPreLoad(EventArgs e) {
    var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
    MyData.BusinessDataStorage.GetData().ForEach(item =>
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterArrayDeclaration(Page, "pageData", serializer.Serialize(item));
    });
    base.OnPreLoad(e); }
```

> **Binding to ASMX Web Services** 
>   To bind RadListView to an ASMX Web
>   Service, you need to set the following properties: 
>   •Location: service base location 
>   •DataPath: Data method name 
>   •CountPath: Count method name, if required 
>   •SortParameterType: Sort expression format, if supported 
>   •FilterParameterType: Filter expression format, if supported
>
> If data and total row count is returned in one and the same service
>   call, the CountPath setting is omitted. In this case, RadListView
>   searches for fields with name Data and Count in the web service JSON
>   response, respectively. To modify the names of the response fields
>   RadListView looks for, set the DataPropertyName and CountPropertyName
>   settings.   Binding to WCF Services For automatic databinding to WCF
>   services, RadListView is configured in an identical way as ASMX Web
>   Services. In this example, RadListView is bound to a WCF Service that
>   returns data and count in a single request:
>
> **Binding to OData Services** 
>   Binding RadListView to OData service is
>   quite straightforward. The only two required parameters are Location
>   and HttpMethod="Get". OData services require GET requests in
>   RadListView. Additionally, if a remote OData request is accessed (and
>   it supports JSONP), ResponseType="JSONP" is also added to ensure
>   RadListView can make a remote service request:

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/listview-clientside-various-datasources.html
http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/listview-clientside-binding-specifics.html

Comment: I have already gone thru this document, but again the question remains the same, how can i assign the parameters when i am not getting the DataBinding tag within clientsettings..

Comment: @Dhaval Is `listView` finding and getting populated with the control correctly?